# Gradle throws an error of expecting EOF, found '<<'.Why?

Tags: java, gradle

I am using the below piece of code to copy and filter the properties from the properties file and it is working fine.There are one variable which is not static and I need to pass as a paramter so it could work on correct file.I am using -Penv=test or -Penv=at but I am getting the error.

```
task createLocalProp(type:Copy) << {
    from "templates/local.properties.template"
    into ("$buildDir/properties")
    def myProps = new Properties()
    file("Properties/${env}/local_${env}.properties").withInputStream{
    myProps.load(it);
    }
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.ReplaceTokens, tokens: myProps)
}
```

Error:

```
C:\GRADLE_WORK\XXXX-GRADLE>gradle -b build_localprop.gradle createLocalProp -Pen
v=test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\GRADLE_WORK\XXX-GRADLE\build_localprop.gradle' line: 37

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\GRADLE_WORK\XXXX-GRADLE\build_localprop.gradle'
.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\GRADLE_WORK\XXX-GRADLE\build_localprop.gradle': 37: expecting
EOF, found '<<' @ line 37, column 33.
     task createLocalProp(type:Copy) << {
                                     ^

  1 error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure right now why the compiler error happens, but you should not configure the task in execution phase, but in configuration phase. `<<` syntax is a shortcut for `doLast` and thus even if it would compile it would probably not work as expected. Remove the `<<` and probably everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the direction.The issue is fixed now.

Comment: Well, it's a generic syntax error essentially meaning there's some sort of discrepancy (missing closing bracket or anything else). In my case it was caused by assignment (=) instead of comparison (==) which was obviously a typo. :)
Just posting for anyone who double checked their closing brackets 5 times in a row and didn't spot any unclosed expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar error reporting the bottom of my gradle file had an error. In reality it was a missing closing bracket in the middle of the file that I missed when doing a diff merge conflict.